# Bug in VS13 regex: wrong order for alternatives?

Tags: c++, regex, visual-studio-2013

I need a regex that captures an argument between parentheses. The blanks before and after the argument should not be captured. For example, `"( ab & c )"` should return `"ab & c"`. The argument can be enclosed into single quotes if leading or trailing blanks are needed. So, `"( ' ab & c ' )"` should return `" ab & c "`.

```
wstring String = L"( ' ab & c ' )";
wsmatch Matches;
regex_match( String, Matches, wregex(L"\\(\\s*(?:'(.+)'|(.+?))\\s*\\)") );
wcout << L"<" + Matches[1].str() + L"> " + L"<" + Matches[2].str() + L">" + L"\n";
// Results in "<> < ' ab & c '>", not OK
```

It seems that the second alternative matched, but it also took the space in front of the first quote! It should have been caught by the `\s` after the opening parenthesis.

Removing the second alternative:

```
regex_match( String, Matches, wregex(L"\\(\\s*(?:'(.+)')\\s*\\)") );
wcout << L"<" + Matches[1].str() + L">" + L"\n";
// Results in "< ab & c >", OK
```

Making it a capturing group of alternatives:

```
regex_match( String, Matches, wregex(L"\\(\\s*('(.+)'|(.+?))\\s*\\)") );
wcout << L"<" + Matches[1].str() + L"> " + L"<" + Matches[2].str() + L"> " + L"<" + Matches[3].str() + L">" + L"\n";
// Results in "<' ab & c '> < ab & c > <> ", OK
```

Am I overlooking anything?

Comment: A strange behavior. Did you try to replace the dots with `[^']` to see what happens? And did you try to do the same without wchar_t? (note that ecmascript regex engine is not very fluent with multibyte characters)

Comment: Very interesting effect - in g++ with libstdc++ it works as in VS2013 but without space at the beginning. In clang++ with libc++ the first group is matched. So it's 3 different behaviors for 3 standard libraries :) regexr.com (I believe javascript variant) thinks that libc++ is correct.

Comment: @Casimir: same problem with "normal" characters; replacing the dots with `[^']` does make it work however. @Predenik: to my opinion the first group should be matched, I posted the question because I know from experience how easy one makes mistakes with regexes...

Comment: I tried to simplified this a bit and report a [bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1371443) on connect, also it looks like it was fixed in later (since gcc 5.0) libstdc++. With some hope it would be resolved by Miscrosoft too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my suggestion that merges two alternatives into 1:

```
wstring String = L"( ' ab & c ' )";
wsmatch Matches;
regex_match( String, Matches, wregex(L"\\(\\s*(')?([^']+)\\1\\s*\\)") );
wcout << L"<" + Matches[2].str() + L"> " + L"\n";
```

The `\(\s*(')?([^']+)\1\s*\)` regex is using a back-reference to make sure we have a `'` at the beginning and the end in order not to capture `'something`. The value is caught into Group 2.

Output:

[image]

Comment: Does it work for you or do you need further assistance?